# Recursive read lock acquisitions not allowed in this mode

Tags: lucene, indexing

Im using Sitecore 7.2 on a split CM/CD environment.

When I publish an item on the CM I get:

```
ManagedPoolThread #73 10:01:10 ERROR Could not update index entry. Action: 'Saved', Item: '{8EDE5C9E-265D-434A-9D1F-763B7755A9A0}' 
Exception: System.Threading.LockRecursionException 
Message: Recursive read lock acquisitions not allowed in this mode. 
Source: System.Core 
at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterReadLockCore(TimeoutTracker timeout) 
at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterReadLock(TimeoutTracker timeout) 
at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterReadLock(Int32 millisecondsTimeout) 
at Sitecore.Search.IndexDeleteContext..ctor(ILuceneIndex index) 
at Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.DeleteItem(Item item) 
at Sitecore.Data.Managers.IndexingProvider.UpdateItem(HistoryEntry entry, Database database) 
at Sitecore.Data.Managers.IndexingProvider.UpdateIndex(HistoryEntry entry, Database database)
```

Which is causing the item to not be indexed on the CD which means it doesnt show up on the page. Not sure why this is ocurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the error is a file locking error, the first thing that I would do (if you have access) is back up and then wipe out your existing indexes on the file system. You can do this by deleting the index files/directories from your `Data/Indexes` folder. Once you have done so, rebuild the indexes and the error should be gone.

The reason why this happens is that sometimes Windows has issues releasing locks from file handles, which could be due to any number of factors. Sometimes, this is caused by the web process currently using the index; other times, a corruption on the last indexing operation; and more.

Clearing out the index files essentially "resets" the solution/wipes the slate as far as indexing goes, enabling you to replace the corrupted files with fresh ones (that are hopefully not corrupted).